# How do I stop an Android TextView with lot of text squeezing out one to its right?

Tags: android, layout, android-linearlayout, textview, android-relativelayout

I'm trying to get two TextViews side-by-side and centered---allowing them to grow as the data grows. When the text is *too* big, I'm ellipsizing it.

The problem I'm having is that, if one of the boxes contains a lot of text, it squeezes the other one out. What I'd like is for the small one to be displayed fully and for the big one to be squeezed more.

At present, when I have the following text in the two boxes

- A big long list of words that pushes the other TextView out
- Foobar

both are getting squeezed.

In this case, I'd like "Foobar" to be displayed fully, with the longer TextView giving up some space---e.g

`...the other TextView out Foobar`

When I get now is

`...that pushes the other TextView out ...ar`

If both text boxes are of similar size, I'd like them both to get a fair share.

My attempt is below.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:ellipsize="start"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:text="A big long list of words that pushes the other TextView out" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:ellipsize="start"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:text="Foobar" />
</LinearLayout>
```

I also tried a relative output (see below)---with a minWidth---but this just squeezed the right most TextView off the parent view completely!

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:ellipsize="start"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:text="A big long list of words that pushes the other TextView out" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/textView1"
        android:minWidth="100dp"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:ellipsize="start"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:text="Foobar" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Anyone know how to make this work?

Comment: Will it always be the TextView1 that has the longer text?

Comment: if you just want to give them equal share then give the linear layout weightSum = 2 and give both the text views 0dp width and layout_weight="1"

Comment: Sometimes TextView1 will be the longer.

Comment: @Anmol. That gives the smaller TextView more space than it needs.

Comment: you can give maxWidth to the views, i think that can help

Comment: If I do maxWidth it won't use all the space if necessary. I don't want to chop off the bigger one if there's space for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at Google's FlexboxLayout. I think that it may have the capability you need to flow your `TextView`s. You can find some documentation [here](https://github.com/google/flexbox-layout) and a tutorial [here](https://blog.stylingandroid.com/flexboxlayout-part-1/).

> FlexboxLayout is a library project which brings the similar capabilities of CSS Flexible Box Layout Module to Android.

**Update:** 
I am unsure that `FlexboxLayout` is the solution. Here is another one that uses `TableLayout` and `TableRow`.

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:shrinkColumns="0">

    <!-- TableLayout is needed to specify shrinkColumns. Ignore "Useless parent" error. -->
    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:ignore="UselessParent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:ellipsize="start"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:text="A big long list of words that pushes the other outwords that pushes the other TextView out"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:text="Foobar"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```